# How to use for loop or a purrr package to simplify repetitive processes in R

Tags: r, function, for-loop, purrr, data-wrangling

Let's say that I ran a survey for 1000 people and asked their age, location, and 10 questions with "select all apply" format (e.g., What are the reasons you like our brand's Product #1? Select all apply),  and each question has 10 items as options (1. it looks fashionable, 2. It is useful, 3. it is a good price, etc.) Here is a code to create a mock dataset.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(writexl)

set.seed(2)

record_id<- c(1:1000)
age<- as.factor(sample (c("teens", "young adults"), replace = T, size = 1000))
region<- as.factor(sample (c("rural", "urban"), replace = T, size = 1000))

N<- 1000
xy <- matrix(NA, nrow = N, ncol= 100)
for (i in 1:N) {
  xy[i, ] <-  sample(c("checked","unchecked"), replace = T, size = 100)
}

xy<- data.frame(xy)

num_questions <- 10
items_per_question <- 10

# Initialize an empty vector to store column names
col_names <- character(0)

# Loop through each group and item, generating column names
for (question in 1:num_questions) {
  for (item in 1:items_per_question) {
    col_name <- paste0("q", question, "_", item)
    col_names <- c(col_names, col_name)
  }
}

colnames(xy) <- col_names
mydf<- data.frame(record_id, age, region, xy)  

# generating some NA to make the dataset realistic 
set.seed(2)
mydf<- mydf %>% mutate(
  across(.cols= (c(4:100)),
         .fns = ~if_else(rbinom(n(), 1, 0.04) == 1L, NA, .x))
)  

mydf[1:5, 1:5]

#  record_id          age region      q1_1      q1_2
#1         1        teens  urban   checked   checked
#2         2        teens  rural unchecked unchecked
#3         3 young adults  urban   checked unchecked
#4         4 young adults  urban   checked unchecked
#5         5 young adults  rural unchecked unchecked
```

My goal is to **create 1) a frequency table with percentages for each item per question where denominator is the number of participants who answered the question (i.e., who checked at least one item listed below that question), 2) that frequency table grouped by different age ,3) that frequency table grouped by different regions.**

In addition, because my colleagues want to create a graph in excel,**I need to export the table to an excel file at the end.**

Here is my attempt to achieve that goal.

```
mydf1_long<- mydf %>%  select(record_id,age, region,  starts_with("q1_")) %>%  
  pivot_longer(-c(1:3), names_to = "item")


mydf1_long %>% filter(value == "checked") %>%  distinct(record_id) %>% 
  count(name = "den") %>% 
  cbind(mydf1_long %>% 
          filter(value == "checked") %>% 
          count(item, name = "num")) %>% arrange(num) %>% 
  mutate(perc = round((num / den) , 2)) %>% select(-num, -den) %>%  write_xlsx("q1.xlsx")


mydf1_long %>% filter(value == "checked") %>%  distinct(record_id, age) %>% 
  count(age, name = "den") %>% 
  right_join(mydf1_long %>% 
               filter(value == "checked") %>% 
               count(age, item, name = "num")) %>% group_by(age) %>% arrange(num, .by_group = TRUE) %>% 
  mutate(perc = round((num / den) , 2)) %>% select(-num, -den) %>%  write_xlsx("q1_age.xlsx")


mydf1_long %>% filter(value == "checked") %>%  distinct(record_id, region) %>% 
  count(region, name = "den") %>% 
  right_join(mydf1_long %>% 
               filter(value == "checked") %>% 
               count(region, item, name = "num")) %>% group_by(region) %>% arrange(num, .by_group = TRUE) %>% 
  mutate(perc = round((num / den) , 2)) %>% select(-num, -den) %>%  write_xlsx("q1_region.xlsx")
```

These are output tables that I would like to have (as excel files)

```
# item perc
# 1   q1_2 0.45
# 2   q1_7 0.47
# 3   q1_1 0.47
# 4   q1_5 0.47
# 5   q1_4 0.48
# 6  q1_10 0.49
# 7   q1_6 0.49
# 8   q1_3 0.49
# 9   q1_9 0.50
# 10  q1_8 0.51

# age          item   perc
# <fct>        <chr> <dbl>
# 1 teens        q1_2   0.42
# 2 teens        q1_7   0.45
# 3 teens        q1_1   0.47
# 4 teens        q1_4   0.47
# 5 teens        q1_5   0.47
# 6 teens        q1_10  0.49
# 7 teens        q1_3   0.49
# 8 teens        q1_8   0.5 
# 9 teens        q1_6   0.51
# 10 teens        q1_9   0.52
# 11 young adults q1_9   0.47
# 12 young adults q1_2   0.47
# 13 young adults q1_6   0.48
# 14 young adults q1_1   0.48
# 15 young adults q1_5   0.48
# 16 young adults q1_4   0.49
# 17 young adults q1_7   0.49
# 18 young adults q1_10  0.49
# 19 young adults q1_3   0.5 
# 20 young adults q1_8   0.52

# region item   perc
# <fct>  <chr> <dbl>
# 1 rural  q1_2   0.43
# 2 rural  q1_1   0.46
# 3 rural  q1_3   0.47
# 4 rural  q1_4   0.47
# 5 rural  q1_6   0.47
# 6 rural  q1_7   0.47
# 7 rural  q1_5   0.48
# 8 rural  q1_10  0.5 
# 9 rural  q1_9   0.51
# 10 rural  q1_8   0.52
# 11 urban  q1_2   0.46
# 12 urban  q1_5   0.47
# 13 urban  q1_7   0.47
# 14 urban  q1_1   0.48
# 15 urban  q1_10  0.48
# 16 urban  q1_4   0.48
# 17 urban  q1_9   0.48
# 18 urban  q1_8   0.5 
# 19 urban  q1_6   0.51
# 20 urban  q1_3   0.52
```

And I would like to have this for the 9 remaining questions but I would like do avoid copying and pasting the same code for q2~ q10. I wonder if I can loop it or map it without having to going through that. Can anyone help me?

Comment: Could you provide a small example table of your desired output?

Comment: Also, could you edit your question to simply include the output of `dput(mydf[1:9,])`? The example data created by your code does not seem to align with what you have for me

Comment: @jpsmith Thanks for letting me know! I fixed the code so it should be good. And I provided a sample of my desired output- I omitted an important piece of information in my earlier post.

Answer (score 0):

I think your long data frame isn't tidy because you have two data items (the question and the response item in a single column - for example "q1_5").  I start by making the data frame tidy because that will simplify the workflow to follow.  [I also introduce missing values at this stage because for some reason I had an error when running your code to create the test data.]

```
> set.seed(123)
> mydf1_long %>% 
+   separate(item, into=c("question", "response"), sep= "_") %>% 
+   mutate(
+     response = as.numeric(response),
+     value = ifelse(rbinom(nrow(.), 1, 0.04) == 1L, NA_character_, value),
+   )
# A tibble: 100,000 × 6
   record_id age   region question response value    
       <int> <fct> <fct>  <chr>       <dbl> <chr>    
 1         1 teens urban  q1              1 unchecked
 2         1 teens urban  q1              2 unchecked
 3         1 teens urban  q1              3 unchecked
 4         1 teens urban  q1              4 checked  
 5         1 teens urban  q1              5 checked  
 6         1 teens urban  q1              6 checked  
 7         1 teens urban  q1              7 unchecked
 8         1 teens urban  q1              8 checked  
 9         1 teens urban  q1              9 unchecked
10         1 teens urban  q1             10 unchecked
# … with 99,990 more rows
```

I intend to use `dplyr::group_walk` to solve your problem  `group_walk` takes a single argument - a function - and applies it sequentially to each group of a grouped data frame.  (Or to the whole data frame if it is ungrouped.)  The function should have two arguments (conventionally `.x` and `.y`).  `.x` contains the rows in the current group.  `.y` is a single row data frame whose columns define the current group.

Start by writing a function that meets these criteria and produces the output you want.  The only slightly complicated piece is constructing the name of the output file.

```
tabulate <- function(.x, .y) {
  tmp <- .x %>% filter(value == "checked")
  # Number of responses per question
  responders <- tmp %>% 
    group_by(question) %>% 
    summarise(n = n())
  # Number of responses per choice
  answers <- tmp %>% 
    group_by(question, response) %>% 
    summarise(r = n(), .groups = "drop")
  # Percentage of response in each category
  pct <- answers %>% 
    left_join(responders, by = "question") %>% 
    mutate(pct = r / n)
  # Create the output file
  pct %>% 
    group_by(question) %>% 
    group_walk(
      function(.x1, .y1) {
        if (nrow(.y) == 0) {
          file_name <- paste0(.y1$question, ".xlsx")
        } else {
          file_name <- paste0(
            .y1$question, 
            "_",
            .y %>% 
              mutate(
                label = str_c(
                  c_across(), sep = "_", collapse = "_")
              ) %>% 
            pull(label), 
            ".xlsx"
          )
        }
        file_name <- str_replace(file_name, " ", "_")
       # For debugging
       # print(file_name)
       # print(.x1)
        .x1 %>% write_xlsx(file_name)
      }
    )
}
```

Now it's a simple matter to create your outputs.  For example:

```
set.seed(123)
mydf1_long %>% 
  separate(item, into=c("question", "response"), sep= "_") %>% 
  mutate(
    response = as.numeric(response),
    value = ifelse(rbinom(nrow(.), 1, 0.04) == 1L, NA_character_, value),
  ) %>% 
  group_walk(tabulate) %>% 
  group_by(age) %>% 
  group_walk(tabulate)
  group_by(region) %>% 
  group_walk(tabulate) %>% 
  group_by(age, region) %>% 
  group_walk(tabulate)
```

Note that I have reversed the order of execution of your loops.  Rather than taking each question in turn and producing the output for each required categorisation in turn, I take each categorisation and produce the output for each question in turn.